# Error al instalar composer en ubuntu 16.04 Lts

Tags: composer

composer en la primera instalación me funcionaba perfectamente, pero cuando lo des instale para actualizar php a 7.2.* me sale el siguiente error

```
`All settings correct for using Composer
Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/alfredo/.composer
```

comoposer lo instale con el siguiente comando `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` al des instalarlo solo lo borre el archivo composer como tal, en la primera instalación me funcionaba perfectamente 
alguna ayuda por favor se los agradece

Comment: Has probado a borrar el directorio .composer de tu home?  Comentarte también que a partir de Ubuntu 16.04 puedes instalar composer con apt-get instalo...

Answer (score 1):

Para eso debes seguir estos sencillos pasos yo lo usé en Unbutu 16.04.

Primero, actualiza la memoria caché del administrador de paquetes ejecutando:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Ahora, instalemos las dependencias. Necesitaremos curl para descargar Composer y php-cli para instalarlo y ejecutarlo. El paquete php-mbstring es necesario para proporcionar funciones para una biblioteca que vamos a utilizar. git es utilizado por Composer para descargar dependencias de proyectos y descomprimir para extraer paquetes comprimidos. Todo se puede instalar con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get install curl php-cli php-mbstring git unzip
```

después lo instalas con el curl de esta manera:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
```

A continuación, ejecuta un script PHP corto para verificar que el instalador coincida con el hash SHA-384 para el último instalador que se encuentra en la página Composer Public Keys / Signatures. Deberas asegurarte de sustituir el último valor hash por el valor resaltado a continuación:

```
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

Para instalar composer globalmente, usa lo siguiente:

```
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Esto descargará e instalará Composer como un system-wide llamado `composer`, en / usr / local / bin.

```
All settings correct for using Composer
```

Downloading 1.1.1...

Composer successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

y ahora puedes probarlo con este comando:

```
composer
```

te debe mostrar algo así:

```
Output
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 1.1.1 2016-05-17 12:25:44

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help                     Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
  -V, --version                  Display this application version
      --ansi                     Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi                  Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction           Do not ask any interactive question
      --profile                  Display timing and memory usage information
      --no-plugins               Whether to disable plugins.
. . .
```